# input type range c кастомным выводом цифр

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, html5

Здравствуйте, подскажите пожалуйста какие варианты возможны для реализации такой задачи?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Есть ползунок (input type range) он управляет каруселью из цифр, выводится три цифры одновременно. И тут загвоздка, вывод одной цифры реализуется без проблем.  Но я так понимаю что для вывод более одной цифры нужно дописывать логику по принципу слайдера (карусель), а ползунок им управляет
Я думал взять готовый слайдер (Slick) и добавить туда  управление через   ползунок. Но мне кажется что это не верное решение....
Знающие люди подскажите.
Возможно это все можно сделать значительно проще?
Готовые решения, библиотеки? Я к сожалению не нашел. Возможно это как-то реализовать без подключения слайдера?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
let output = document.querySelectorAll("output");
let input = document.querySelector("input");

input.addEventListener("input", function() {
  if ((parseInt(input.value) - 1) < input.min) {
    output[0].innerHTML = "";
  } else {
    output[0].innerHTML = parseInt(input.value) - 1;
  }
  output[1].innerHTML = parseInt(input.value);
  if ((parseInt(input.value) + 1) > input.max) {
    output[2].innerHTML = "";
  } else {
    output[2].innerHTML = parseInt(input.value) + 1;
  }
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #272727;
  color: white;
}

#wrapper {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-top: 1px solid transparent;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.wrap {
  width: 200px;
  height: 40px;
  background: gray;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  align-items: center;
}

output:nth-child(2) {
  color: red;
  font-size: 25px;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div class="wrap">
    <output></output>
    <output>0</output>
    <output>1</output>
  </div>
  <div class="wrap">
    <input type="range" max="100" min="0" value="0" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо данный вариант подошел своей простотой.  Я думал что без слайдера не обойтись.

Comment: Всегда пожалуйста....

Comment: @Air и Правда хорошо сделано!

Answer (score 4):

Со слайдером

```js
$('#slick').slick({
  infinite: true,
  slidesToShow: 3,
  slidesToScroll: 1
});
$('#range').change(function() {
  const val = $(this).val();
  $('#slick').slick('slickGoTo', val);
})
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.slick/1.6.0/slick.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.slick/1.6.0/slick.min.js"></script>
<div id="slick">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
  <div>5</div>
  <div>6</div>
</div>
<input type="range" id="range" value="0" min="0" max="5">
```

Вариант без слайдера

```js
function update() {
  var val = parseInt($('#range').val());
  $('#slick div').hide();
  $('#slick div:nth-child(' + val + ')').show();
  $('#slick div:nth-child(' + (val - 1) + ')').show();
  $('#slick div:nth-child(' + (val + 1) + ')').show();
}
update();
$('#range').change(update);
```

```css
#slick div {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="slick">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
  <div>5</div>
  <div>6</div>
</div>
<input type="range" id="range" value="1" min="1" max="6">
```

Comment: Спасибо,  за решение с слайдером)) . Выбрал вариант без слайдера так как он проще, думал что так не получится.